# Обработка нажатий на кнопку в ListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview

Помогите с обработкой нажатий на кнопки которые установлены в ListView через адаптер. `ListAdapter adaptiruy = new SimpleAdapter(this, pizzaNames, R.layout.adapter_backet, from, to);
            listView.setAdapter(adaptiruy);`
Собственно нужно что б при нажатии увеличивалось количество элементов pizza +1 или -1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код адаптера:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/for_bucket_adapter"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textok1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textok2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="22sp"
        android:layout_height="22sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/plusss"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="22sp"
        android:layout_height="5sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/minuss"
        android:onClick="Click"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

и код активности:

```
public class BasketPage extends Activity {
        List<Map<String, String>> pizzaNames = new ArrayList<>();

        public String name;
        public String phoneNumber;
        public String street;
        public String home;
        public String porch;
        public String level;
        public String apprt;
        public String comment;
        public boolean b;
        //private Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.minus);


        WorkBD workBD;
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        public ListView listView;

        public int [] PizzaMass = new int [5];
        int indexhelper = -1;



        public void creator() {
            System.out.println(MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount());
            if (MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Пепперони ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
                PizzaMass [0] = ++indexhelper;
            }
            if (MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Кальцоне ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.calzone.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
                PizzaMass [1] = ++indexhelper;
            }
            if (MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Четыре сезона ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
                PizzaMass [2] = ++indexhelper;
            }
            if (MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Четыре сыра ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
                PizzaMass [3] = ++indexhelper;
            }

            if (MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Мексиканская ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.mexican.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
                PizzaMass [4] = ++indexhelper;
            }
        }

        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);
            mainActivity= new MainActivity();
            creator();
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.titles);
            String [] from = {"text1" , "text2"};
            String [] fromik = {"ftext1" , "ftext2"};
            int [] to = {R.id.textok1 , R.id.textok2};
            int [] too = {R.id.ftext1 , R.id.ftext2};
            ListAdapter adaptiruy = new SimpleAdapter(this, pizzaNames, R.layout.adapter_backet, from, to);
            listView.setAdapter(adaptiruy);
            workBD = new WorkBD(this);
            culculateFprice();

        }
...
}
```

Comment: я бы вам посоветовал посмотреть в сторону recyclerView

Comment: Создайте OnClickListener и присваивайте его в адаптере. Индекс можно например засунуть в setTag

Comment: Можете подробнее описать как это сделать пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы при создании адаптера передаёте ему массив.
И чтобы добавить новую строку по нажатию на клавишу вам нужно именно в адаптере назначить действие на кнопку, как в обычной активности через setOnClickListener
Внутри адаптера можно взаимодействовать с массивом, который вы ему передали
Т. Е. Вам нужно добавить новый элемент в массив
И уведомить адаптер об изменениях командой notifydatasetchanged();